# How to send an input request to user and store the answer in telegram bot

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm writing a telegram bot in golang using github.com/Syfaro/telegram-bot-api. And I need following:

1. A user sends a command
2. Bot asks the user a question
3. The user answers
4. Then bot does some calculations and sends an answer

I can't find how to send the user an input request. Can anyone, please, help me with it?

```golang
updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/" + bot.Token)

for update := range updates {
        chatID := update.Message.Chat.ID

        if update.Message.IsCommand() {
            msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(chatID, "")
            switch update.Message.Command() {
            case "command":
                response := tgbotapi.inputRequest(chatId, "Enter some text:")  //pseudocode
                msg.Text = response.Text                                      //
                bot.Send(msg)                                                //
            }
        } else {
            bot.Send(tgbotapi.NewMessage(chatID, "I don't know what to say"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is an input request and why do you need to send one? Why not just reply the user with a message?

Comment: @rotimi-best, I mean, for example, the bot asks a user of they name (i called in "input request") and then prints "Hello, <name>"